# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy'

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

Tried Adding to classpath log4jdbc.log4j2.jar
and also adding tomcat/lib but does not find it.

server.xml has

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/myDS" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy"
              url="jdbc:log4jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://abc:1433;DatabaseName=test;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=false"
              username="uuser"
              password="$bb@"
              maxActive="120"
              minIdle="5"
              maxWait="10000"
          />
```

using jdk 7 and tomcat 7

can i use  driverClassName="net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy" OR driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"  any ?

Comment: Which version of log4jdbc.log4j2.jar are you using?

Comment: log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4-1.12.jar